# Programmatically accessing Visual Studio Solution Explorer search box

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, envdte, solution-explorer, visual-studio-automation

I am working on a VS extension that needs to select a specific project in the solution. However, if the user has previously typed any text in the solution explorer search box, when I find the project item, calling

```
.Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect)
```

on it does not work. My idea is to access the search box and clear it before selecting the project. Unfortunatelly, I was not able to find any clue on how to do that, not in documentation and tutorials, not even inspecting the

```
dte.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer
```

object. Am I doing it wrong so I can't find a solution for something that should be more than easy to do?

Thank you in advance, any ideas/help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the search box:

```
IVsSolutionUIHierarchyWindow solutionWindows = (IVsSolutionUIHierarchyWindow)VsShellUtilities.GetUIHierarchyWindow(this.ServiceProvider, VSConstants.StandardToolWindows.SolutionExplorer);    

if (solutionWindows is IVsWindowSearch)
{
    var slw = solutionWindows as IVsWindowSearch;
    slw.ClearSearch();
}
```